# Kick glue Crawler whenever a file lands in S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have the following code to kick glue crawler whenever a file lands in S3 bucket. I have added trigger and gave the bucket location with S3 put object. However, lambda is not kicking the crawler automatically as soon as the file lands. But, if I click test on the lambda function it kicks Glue Crawler. Please let me what is the issue here.

```
    import json
import boto3

print('Loading function')

glue = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name='us-east-1',endpoint_url='https://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    try:
       glue.start_crawler(Name='test')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error starting crawler')
        raise e
```

Answer (score 1):

In AWS Lambda -> add a Trigger -> In trigger configuration select S3 ->  Select bucket name, etc.

After adding the trigger, when a file is uploaded to the bucket, the lambda will be triggered.